# Как преобразовать троичную булеву матрицу в двоичную C++

Tags: c++, матрицы

Добрый день. Скажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать на С++ преобразование троичной булевой матрицы в двоичную. То есть перебор возможных значений 0 или 1 на месте "-".
Например
Исходная матрица:

0 1 - 0 
- 0 - 1 
0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0

Конечная матрица:

0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0

Comment: В каких случая на месте `-` вознаикает 0 или 1? И почему исходная и конечная матрица разной размерности?

Comment: В конечной матрице скорее всего подставляются все варианты (`0`/`1`) вместо `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да просто сгенерировать все возможные кортежи... [Вот](http://ideone.com/tF4UWo), на коленке набросано, но вроде работает. Вместо `-` используется `-1`:

```
vector<vector<int>> src =
{
    { 0, 1, -1, 0},
    {-1, 0, -1, 1},
    { 0, 0,  0, 0},
    { 1, 1,  1, 0}
};

vector<vector<int>> dest;

void make_tuples(vector<int> s, back_insert_iterator<vector<vector<int>>> d)
{
    auto i = find(s.begin(),s.end(),-1);
    if (i == s.end())
    {
        d = s;
        return;
    }
    *i = 0;
    make_tuples(s,d);
    *i = 1;
    make_tuples(s,d);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < src.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (any_of(src[i].begin(),src[i].end(),[](int j){ return j == -1; }))
        {
            make_tuples(src[i],back_inserter(dest));
        }
        else
            dest.push_back(src[i]);
    }

    for(auto row : dest)
    {
        for(auto i: row) cout << i << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!